# Exponentiation of matrix in Jordan block shape

Tags: matrices

I'm trying to calculate $A^k$ for a 3x3 Jordan block matrix with 2 in the diagonal. I found this question in a previous exam for CS students, who were expected to solve it within 12 minutes at most.

At first, I attempted $A = VDV^{-1}$ to continue with $A^k = VD^kV^{-1}$. I found the triple Eigenvalue 2 but the corresponding Eigensystem only has dimension 1, so the matrix sadly is not diagonizable.

Given that, I'm not sure how I can solve this quickly. I would likely try to find the recursion formula for cells 1-1, 1-2 and 1-3 and prove each by induction. All other cells are symmetric (cells below the diagonal being 0 obviously). I recognize cell 1-1 is 2^k and hope the others are not too complicated, but this might be a gamble under time pressure.

Is there a different, better way?

Comment: Bother matrix stuff does not seem to work in comments. You mean the matrix has first row 2,1,0, second row 0,2,1 and bottom row 0,0,2?

Comment: @almagest Yes, exactly

Comment: Hmmm. Sorry needs a little more thought!

Comment: This might be helpful: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan_normal_form#Powers

Comment: The (corrected) WA link: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%7B%7B2%2C1%2C0%7D%2C%7B0%2C2%2C1%7D%2C%7B0%2C0%2C2%7D%7D%5Ek

Comment: @user84413 That is indeed very relevant!

Comment: My [answer here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/910635/power-of-a-matrix-given-its-jordan-form/910658#910658) could help you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Write your Jordan block as $2 I + N$ where $N = \pmatrix{0 & 1 & 0\cr 0 & 0 & 1\cr 0 & 0 & 0\cr}$.  Note that $N^2 = \pmatrix{0 & 0 & 1\cr 0 & 0 & 0\cr 0 & 0 & 0\cr}$ and $N^3 = 0$.  So $$(2I+N)^k = 2^k I + k\; 2^{k-1} N + {k \choose 2} 2^{k-2} N^2 = \pmatrix{2^k & k\; 2^{k-1} & {k \choose 2} 2^{k-2}\cr
0 & 2^k & k\; 2^{k-1}\cr 0 & 0 & 2^k\cr}$$

Answer (score 0):

I think I have gone over the 12 minutes, but you have to work out a few small cases, guess that $A^k=\left(\begin{array}{ccc}2^k & 2^{k-1}k & 2^{k-3}k(k-1)\\ 0 & 2^k & 2^{k-1}k \\ 0 & 0 & 2^k\end{array}\right)$ and then prove it by induction.