# Matrix to the infinite power shall be zero

Tags: linear-algebra, discrete-time

Hello fellow people here.

I found a problem, which started to haunt me: Defining the system: $$ e_{k+1} = A e_{k} $$
With $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}, e_k \in \mathbb{R}^n, e_0 \text{ given} $ (Hoping I do not mix here something up with the dimensions.

And now the problem: Which conditions must $A$ satisfy, such that: $\lim_{k\to \infty} ||e_k|| = 0$

I made the following considerations : $\lim_{k\to \infty} ||e_k|| = \lim_{n\to\infty} A^n = 0$ This due to the fact, that $e_{k+1} = A^k e_0$. So we have to make conditions for A. Am I missing something? But the problem is just starting here, what shall I do with that? This basically means, that the norm for A must be less then 1, and what shall I do with that? Which conditions must A fullfill, that this satisfied?

Thank you for your answer in advance.

Comment: $\|A\|<1$ is sufficient but not necessary. Nilpotent matrices also satisfy this property.

Comment: Is there also a necessary condition @KaviRamaMurthy ?

Comment: If $\|e_k\| \to 0$ for all choices of $e_0$ then every eigen value $\lambda$ of $A$ necessarily has modulus less than $1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the eigenvalues $\lambda_i$ of $A\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ must be such that $|\lambda_i|<1$, for $i=1,\dots,n$, is necessary and sufficient for $\|e_k\|\rightarrow 0$ as $k\rightarrow\infty$. That is, all the eigenvalues are inside a unit disk in the complex plane.

It is easy to see through the eigenvalue decomposition
$$
A^k = V \Lambda^k V^{-1}
$$
where $V$ is the matrix of eigenvectors and $\Lambda = \text{diag}(\lambda_1,\dots,\lambda_n)$. Therefore, $0\leq \|A^k\| \leq \|V\| \|\Lambda^k\| \|V^{-1}\|$ and
$$
\lim_{k\rightarrow\infty} \|\Lambda^k\| = 0
$$
if and only if $|\lambda_i|<1$, for $i=1,\dots,n$.
Similar arguments can be made using the Jordan normal form (see https://math.stackexchange.com/a/910658/442550).