# Diagonalization method on triangular matrix to compute large power

Tags: linear-algebra, diagonalization

I have a triangular matrix $A$, and I need to find $A^{20}$.

$$
A =
\begin{bmatrix}
3&1&0\\
0&3&1\\
0&0&3\\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

I tried to use deagonalization method, but can't seem to find the correct eigen values and vectors.

Using $|A-\lambda I|=0$, I get $(3-\lambda)^3 = 0 \implies \lambda = 3$. So I'm guessing the eigen values all are 3?

For eigen vectors, using $|A-\lambda I|x=0$, I get $x_y = -x_z$. I'm not sure what to do next.

Comment: Binomial coefficients.   You have $A = 3I + N$  The important thing is that $N$  and $3I$  commute, while $N$  is nilpotent: $N^3 = 0$   In general, when $BC = CB $  with square matrices, then $(B+C)^2 = B^2 + 2BC + C^2,$  then $(B+C)^3 = B^3 + 3 B^2 C + 3 B C^2 + C^3,$   and so on

Comment: @WillJagy I see thank you! Would it mean however that I would need to expand and calculate a binomial to the power of 20?

Comment: You are   missing the significance of $N^3 = 0$

Comment: Lenny White: "Would it mean however that I would need to expand and calculate a binomial to the power of 20?"  Yes, that method ought to work well using the nilpotence of N.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This matrix is a Jordan block, it cannot be diagonalized.

For $k \ge 2$, we have
$$A^k=\begin{bmatrix} 3^k & k\cdot 3^{k-1} & \binom{k}{2}3^{k-2} \\ 0 & 3^k & k \cdot 3^{k-1} \\ 0 & 0 & 3^k\end{bmatrix}$$

using the formula stated [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/910658/306553).